# recyclerView whit multi view type get messed up on scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a recyclerView which contains three type of view ; in the view type 2 i am checking if the file exits on the internal storage so i load it from storage and if 
 it is not i show a small image view in center of view to download it . when user click download image view the image changes from download icon to pause icon but this happen for some other rows ...

the mainly accepted answers to this question are

1. holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
   but this ruin the purpose of recyclerView

2.override this methods

```
@Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position; } 

@Override  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position; }
```

and my code

```
  @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   int type = messages.get(position).getType();
    if (type==1) {
        return 1;
    }else if (type==2) {
        return 2 ;
    }else if (type==3) {
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

3. setHasStableIds(true);
   not Working

4.write both if and else conditions in  onBindViewHolder

```
  switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
           case 1 :
               SimpleHolder  simpleHolder = (SimpleHolder)holder;
               simpleHolder.tv_text.setText(message.getMessage());
               simpleHolder.tv_time.setText(time);
               if (message.getLiked()==0) {
                   simpleHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.unlike));
               }else {
                   simpleHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.like));
               }

               break;
           case 2 :


               ImageHolder imageHolder = (ImageHolder)holder;
               //in method esme folder va esme aks ro migire o check mikone bebine mojode ya na
                if (isFileExists(Config.Folders.IMAGES ,message.getUrl())) {
                    imageHolder.circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageHolder.iv_download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Glide.with(context).load(getFile(Config.Folders.IMAGES,message.getUrl())).apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

                    ) .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                            ((ImageHolder) holder).iv_picture.setImageDrawable(resource);
                        }
                    });
                    imageHolder.iv_picture.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(getFile(Config.Folders.IMAGES,message.getUrl())));
                }else {
                    imageHolder.iv_download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageHolder.circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Glide.with(context).load(Config.MESSAGE_THUMB_ADDRESS+message.getThumb()).apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.white))
                    ).into(imageHolder.iv_picture);
                }

                imageHolder.tv_time.setText(time);
               if (message.getMessage()!=null) {
                   imageHolder.tv_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   imageHolder.tv_text.setText(message.getMessage());
               }else {
                   imageHolder.tv_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
               if (message.getLiked()==0) {
                   imageHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.unlike));
               }else {
                   imageHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.like));
               }

               break;
```

but still none of them works
 the whole code of my adapter class is

```
public class Message_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Message> messages;
ClickListener clickListener;

public Message_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
    this.context = context;
    this.messages = messages;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

public interface ClickListener {
    public void picture_imageClicked(int position, View view, CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar, ImageView iv_download);

    public void picture_likeClicked(int position, View view);

    public void picture_commentClicked(int position, View view);

    public void simple_likeClicked(int position, View view);

    public void simple_commentClicked(int position, View view);

    public void video_imageClicked(int position, View view, CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar, ImageView iv_download);

    public void video_likeClicked(int position, View view);

    public void video_commentClicked(int position, View view);

}

public void setCliclListener(ClickListener cliclListener) {
    this.clickListener = cliclListener;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == 1) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_simple, parent, false);
        return new SimpleHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == 2) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_picture, parent, false);
        CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar = (CircularProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.cp_picturee);
        circularProgressBar.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        circularProgressBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        circularProgressBar.setProgressBarWidth(10);
        circularProgressBar.setBackgroundProgressBarWidth(5);
        int animationDuration = 2500; // 2500ms = 2,5s
        // circularProgressBar.setProgressWithAnimation(65, animationDuration);
        return new ImageHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == 3) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_video, parent, false);
        CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar = (CircularProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.cp_video);
        circularProgressBar.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        circularProgressBar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        circularProgressBar.setProgressBarWidth(10);
        circularProgressBar.setBackgroundProgressBarWidth(5);
        return new VideoHolder(view);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("The type has to be ONE or TWO");
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message = messages.get(position);
    String time = "00:00";
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(message.getUpdated_at());
        time = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm").format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 1:
            SimpleHolder simpleHolder = (SimpleHolder) holder;
            simpleHolder.tv_text.setText(message.getMessage());
            simpleHolder.tv_time.setText(time);
            if (message.getLiked() == 0) {
                simpleHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.unlike));
            } else {
                simpleHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.like));
            }

            break;
        case 2:


            ImageHolder imageHolder = (ImageHolder) holder;
            //in method esme folder va esme aks ro migire o check mikone bebine mojode ya na
            if (isFileExists(Config.Folders.IMAGES, message.getUrl())) {
                imageHolder.circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageHolder.iv_download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(context).load(getFile(Config.Folders.IMAGES, message.getUrl())).apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

                ).into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                        ((ImageHolder) holder).iv_picture.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    }
                });
                imageHolder.iv_picture.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(getFile(Config.Folders.IMAGES, message.getUrl())));
            } else {
                imageHolder.iv_download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageHolder.circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Glide.with(context).load(Config.MESSAGE_THUMB_ADDRESS + message.getThumb()).apply(new RequestOptions()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.white))
                ).into(imageHolder.iv_picture);
            }

            imageHolder.tv_time.setText(time);
            if (message.getMessage() != null) {
                imageHolder.tv_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageHolder.tv_text.setText(message.getMessage());
            } else {
                imageHolder.tv_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (message.getLiked() == 0) {
                imageHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.unlike));
            } else {
                imageHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.like));
            }

            break;
        case 3:
            VideoHolder videoHolder = (VideoHolder) holder;
            videoHolder.tv_time.setText(time);
            if (message.getMessage() != null) {
                videoHolder.tv_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                videoHolder.tv_text.setText(message.getMessage());
            } else {
                videoHolder.tv_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (message.getLiked() == 0) {
                videoHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.unlike));
            } else {
                videoHolder.iv_like.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.like));
            }

            Glide.with(context).load(Config.VIDEO_PIC_ADDRES + message.getThumb()).apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)

            ).into(videoHolder.iv_picture);


            if (isFileExists(Config.Folders.VIDEOS, message.getUrl())) {
                videoHolder.circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                videoHolder.iv_download.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.play));
            } else {
                videoHolder.iv_download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                videoHolder.circularProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                videoHolder.iv_download.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.download));
            }

            String lenth = message.getLenth() < 1024 ? message.getLenth() + " kb" : message.getLenth() / 1024 + " mb";
            videoHolder.tv_video_time.setText(message.getTime() + " | " + lenth);


            break;


        default:
            break;


    }
}

public boolean isFileExists(String folderName, String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        filename = "null";
    }
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NoorAlSalehin/" + folderName, filename);
    return file.exists();
}

public File getFile(String folderName, String filename) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NoorAlSalehin/" + folderName, filename);
    return file;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int type = messages.get(position).getType();
    if (type == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (type == 2) {
        return 2;
    } else if (type == 3) {
        return 3;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

class SimpleHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_text, tv_time;
    ImageView iv_like, iv_comment;

    public SimpleHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_simple_text);
        iv_like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_simple_like);
        iv_comment = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_simple_comment);
        tv_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_simple_time);
        iv_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickListener.simple_likeClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            }
        });
        iv_comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickListener.simple_commentClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            }
        });
    }
}

class ImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView iv_picture, iv_download, iv_like, iv_comment;
    TextView tv_text, tv_time;

    CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar;

    public ImageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        iv_download = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_picture_download);
        iv_picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_picture_image);
        circularProgressBar = (CircularProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cp_picturee);
        tv_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_picture_text);
        iv_comment = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_picture_comment);
        tv_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_picture_time);
        iv_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickListener.picture_imageClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view, circularProgressBar, iv_download);
            }
        });
        iv_like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_picture_like);
        iv_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickListener.picture_likeClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            }
        });
        iv_comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                clickListener.picture_commentClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            }
        });
    }
}

class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //  ImageView iv_picture   , iv_like , iv_comment;
    ImageView iv_picture, iv_download, iv_like, iv_comment;
    TextView tv_text, tv_time, tv_video_time;
    //  CircleProgressView circleProgressView ;
    CircularProgressBar circularProgressBar;

    public VideoHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        iv_download = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_video_download_playy);
        iv_picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_video_image);
        //    circleProgressView=(CircleProgressView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cp_video_download);
        circularProgressBar = (CircularProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cp_video);
        tv_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video_text);
        iv_comment = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_video_comment);
        tv_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video_time);
        iv_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickListener.video_imageClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view, circularProgressBar, iv_download);
            }
        });
        tv_video_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_video_video_time);
        iv_like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_video_like);
        iv_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickListener.video_likeClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            }
        });
        iv_comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                clickListener.video_commentClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

}

Comment: For starts, you should remove all of that CircularProgressBar code from onCreateViewHolder and put in on onBindViewHolder.

Comment: noting changes still :(

Comment: I suggest splitting `onBindViewHolder` into a `bind(Message)` method inside each ViewHolder and calling it instead of having a huge switch. And you probably don't clear ongoing Glide asynchronous requests during scroll, hence images getting messed up.

Comment: you should be checking your item view type in onBindViewHolder according to the position with help your messages array like you are doing in on ```int type = messages.get(position).getType();```

Comment: Just a note: which is nothing to do with your problem:  Do not create new objects in your onBindViewHolder method.

Comment: @mudit_sen tenx for your comment ;  so if i check view type in onBindviewHolder then  
getitemViewType should return position ? if yes  how can i return proper view type in onCreateViewHolder . and i could not get you whats your mean to not make object in onBindViewHolder .